# Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo?

Tags: android-intent, kotlin

I am developing a new app when user clicks icon I want to lauch activity but when click icon app crashes

below my Logcat error

```
Process: com.empowered.healo, PID: 19079
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.empowered.healo/com.empowered.healo.ui.screens.therapy.TherapyInformationFragment}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.empowered.healo.ui.screens.therapy.TherapyInformationFragment cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
```

below icon onclick code

```
if(it.key.endsWith("_rf")) {
       attentionIcon.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(context!!, R.color.therapyInfoRedFlag))
            attentionIcon.setOnClickListener {
                val intent = Intent(context, TherapyInformationFragment::class.java)
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        } else if(it.key.endsWith("_yf")) {
            attentionIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_therapy_info_yellow_flag_attention)
            attentionIcon.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(context!!, R.color.therapyInfoYellowWhiteFlag))
            attentionIcon.setOnClickListener {
                val intent = Intent(context!!, TherapyInformationFragment::class.java)
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }else{
            attentionIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_therapy_info_yellow_flag_attention)
            attentionIcon.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(context!!, R.color.therapyInfoYellowWhiteFlag))
            attentionIcon.setOnClickListener {
                val intent = Intent(context, TherapyInformationFragment::class.java)
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
```

below my updated code please give me suggestions

```
if(it.key.endsWith("_rf")) {
            attentionIcon.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(context!!, R.color.therapyInfoRedFlag))
            attentionIcon.setOnClickListener {
                val newFragment = TherapyInformationFragment()
                val transaction = childFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                transaction.replace(R.id.therapy_fragment, newFragment)
                transaction.addToBackStack(null)
                transaction.commit()
            }


        } else if(it.key.endsWith("_yf")) {
            attentionIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_therapy_info_yellow_flag_attention)
            attentionIcon.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(context!!, R.color.therapyInfoYellowWhiteFlag))
            attentionIcon.setOnClickListener {
                val newFragment = TherapyInformationFragment()
                val transaction = childFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                transaction.replace(R.id.therapy_fragment, newFragment)
                transaction.addToBackStack(null)
                transaction.commit()
            }
        }else{
            attentionIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_therapy_info_yellow_flag_attention)
            attentionIcon.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(context!!, R.color.therapyInfoYellowWhiteFlag))
            attentionIcon.setOnClickListener {
                val newFragment = TherapyInformationFragment()
                val transaction = childFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                transaction.replace(R.id.therapy_fragment, newFragment)
                transaction.addToBackStack(null)
                transaction.commit()
            }
```

Comment: `TherapyInformationFragment` is not an activity, but a fragment. These are handled differently https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments

Comment: @tynnI checked link I did not understand what is your suggestion to implement correctly

Comment: When you call `startActivity()`, the `Intent` you pass as an argument must resolve to an `Activity`. You, however, are creating an `Intent` that resolves to a `Fragment`. You are trying to launch a `Fragment` instead of an `Activity`, and that isn't possible. `Fragment`s are hosted by an `Activity`. Please have a look at some more HOWTO videos for Android beginners.

Comment: @DavidWasser can you check my updated code

Comment: So what happens now?

Comment: @DavidWasser what I want to achieve there that when user clicks icon in fragment I want to start a new fragment user go to  a new fragment when clicks icon. do you understand my above implemenent  correctly

Comment: @DavidWasser app crashes

Comment: Please post the error and stacktrace from logcat in your question

Comment: @DavidWasser I removed that code how can I implement my task correctly when user clicks icon in fragment I want to start fragment

Comment: @DavidWasser I posted what I have tried already

Comment: Please post the current error you are getting. You should now be getting a different error.